# Bessel integral with a square-root trigonometric argument?

Tags: integration, closed-form, bessel-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I am seeking a closed form solution to the following integral:

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} I_0(b \sqrt{1 - a^2 cos^2\phi}) d\phi$

where $I_0(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind of order 0.

I have seen a similar question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647681/integration-with-a-bessel-function), but I'm not sure how much it helps me.

Comment: Do $2 \int_0^\pi$ since $\cos$ is even.  Why do you think there is a closed form?  Maybe first see if you can do the special case $a=b=1$, that is: $\int_0^\pi I_o(\sin\theta)\,d\theta$.